# Expresiones regulares en java:

Tags: java

El ejercicio me pide validar un número entero negativo y además el número a de ser insertado mediante teclado:

pude hacer lo siguiente:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Inroduzca el número entero negativo: ");
    String txt = sc.nextLine();
    
    
}
public static boolean negativos(String texto){
    return texto.matches("^-[0-9]+$");
    
}//Si hay quien puede echarme una mano, se lo agradecería:
```

Comment: ¿Qué problema tienes?

Comment: Mi problema está en que ya no se seguir. Si pongo el número negativo lo acepta y si pongo un positivo lo acepta igual entonces no se que opereciones hacr para que no me acepte los ositivos y que sólo me acepte los negativos

Comment: ¿Puedes poner todo el código? Aquí no veo como llamas al método `negativos` tras obtener la entrada del usuario

Comment: import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Inroduzca el número entero negativo: ");
        String txt = sc.nextLine();
        
        
    }
    public static boolean negativos(String texto){
        return texto.matches("^-[0-9]+$");
        
    }//Es todo lo que pude hacer.

Comment: El código debe ir como edición de la pregunta. Como verás, el código es ilegible en los comentarios.